# Optional routing parameters ar not passed on Prem

Tags: sapui5, sap-enterprise-portal

Hello,

we are facing an issue with passing optional parameters using routing.
Parameters are passed to another view when the app runs on BTP, but not on Prem.

The route is defined as follows:

```js
{
name: "routname",
pattern: "thisisname/{mandaroty1},{mandatory2}/:?optional:",
target: ["targetName"]
}
```

This is how I navigate:

```js
oRouter.navTo("routname", {
mandatory1: "test",
mandatory2: "test2",
"?optional": {
optional1: "value1",
optional2: "value2"
}
});
```

In target view:
in onInit:

```js
var oRouter = this.getRouter();
oRouter.getRoute("shapeIT").attachPatternMatched(this._onRouteMatched, this);
```

in _onRouteMatched:

```js
_onRouteMatched: function (oEvent) {
            var oArgs = oEvent ? oEvent.getParameter("arguments") : null;
            console.log(oArgs);
}
```

In console of the onPrem I see as follows:

```js
{
mandatory1: "test",
mandatory2: "test2",
"?optional": undefined
}
```

On BTP I see all values.

What do I miss?

Comment: With which SAPUI5 version is the app on premise running? You can find it out by pressing [\[Ctrl\]+\[Shift\]+\[Left-Alt\]/\[Left-Option\]+[P\]](https://sdk.openui5.org/nightly/#/topic/616a3ef07f554e20a3adf749c11f64e9%23loio616a3ef07f554e20a3adf749c11f64e9).

Comment: Is the app running in an FLP shell? Is the issue reproducible if it's run standalone without FLP?

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann, the version is 1.71.48, the app runs in iView of SAP portal, not in  FLP.

Comment: And with which SAPUI5 version is the app running in BTP? Is the app in BTP running without FLP there either?

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann on BTP it was 1.96, no FLP.

Comment: Try running the app with SAPUI5 1.71.48 on BTP and let us know if the issue is reproducible there. If not, it's likely an issue with the iView environment.

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann retested it on BTP, not working there as well. It works from version 1.75. Strange...

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass an object in the optional parameter. That's cleaver but I believe the problem is because of that. I would recommend using a `JSON.stringify()` to convert your optional parameters to a string and convert the string back to a JS object by using  `JSON.parse()` on your `_onRouteMatched` handler.

Comment: I tried to pass a simple string there - still undefined.